# RXJS Observable Transform Array To Multiple Values

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm making an Angular 2 HTTP get request and in return I get 
`Observable<Message[]>`  I want to transform this observable into multiple emit.
So let's say the server returned Message array with length 3.
I would like to get 3 notification in my subscribe call (on for each value in the array) instead of getting one call with the array.

e.g :
['Hello','Hey','Howdy'] - > 'Hello', 'Hey','Howdy'

**I found an operator that does transform the array (Observable.for),** but this operator takes as an argument an array and not an Observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Observable.from(yourRequest())
    .flatMap(msgList => Observable.from(msgList))
    .subscribe(msg => console.log(msg));
```

`yourRequest()` in this case should return array.

If `yourRequest()` returns `Observable` then:

```
yourRequest().flatMap(msgList => Observable.from(msgList))
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: since msgList carries over to Observable.from, `flatMap(msgList => Observable.from(msgList))` can be written as `  .flatMap(Rx.Observable.from)
`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `concatAll` operator to flatten the array (`mergeAll` will work as well).

```
Observable.of(['Hello','Hey','Howdy'])
  .concatAll()
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

See demo: https://jsbin.com/gaxajex/3/edit?js,console

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you want to use something like [concatMap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/concatmap.md). By using `concatMap`, you can map values(`Message` array in your case) to inner observable, and then you can subscribe these values in order.

```
yourRequest.concatMap(i: Message => Observable.of(i)).subscribe(i => {
     //sendNotification(i);
});
```

You can also take a look at [this page](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html).

I hope it helps!